# Was PAL or NTSC encoder IC a critical component in early video games?

Tags: game-consoles, ntsc, pal, composite-video, secam

I have an old Philips Videopac C52 video game console of the  Philips Odyssey 2 family like the G-7000 with 128-byte RAM:

[image]

While checking its boards to compare with the schematics I got for the G-7000 I found that the PAL encoder (The C52 that I have is made in France) does not use a monolitic integrated circuit but it uses instead a transistor-based circuit that integrates both the PAL encoder and the RF modulator:

[image]

In the G-7000 schematics the PAL decoder is annotated IC679 but the IC type is not indicated:

[image]

I found on the internet a photo of the IC679 but could not read its type and maybe it is intentionally erased:

[image]

What gets me to think that the video encoder might have been a critical component is that even in the G-7000 there is an option to either use the IC or extend the board to use an external circuit for the encoder:

[image]

My question is:

Was the PAL/NTSC video encoder IC a critical component (cost-wise, availability...) in early video game consoles like RAM for early microcomputers?
What was the IC679?

Comment: The C52 was a french market version of the G-7000. France didn't use PAL, they used SECAM, so that might be the answer for not using a PAL colour decoder chip.

Comment: How would the PAL encoder could be a bottleneck and for what, since that is what you ask? For the second question, on IC679 it reads 612160-3 and seems to have manufacturer logo of EXAR. And true, that would not be a PAL but a SECAM model which explains not having a PAL encoder.

Comment: The copy of the service manual shows most probably a series of test pads, not somewhere to attach an external PCB. All except one is clearly marked with what voltage or waveform you ought to get at that point.

Comment: @UncleBod thank you it makes sense. I should have thought about it. Tonight I will check the video waveform.

Comment: In the title of your question you're asking about a "decoder". But in the body you're asking about the "encoder".

Comment: @Justme I explained my point of view. A no can be an answer to my question otherwise I wouldn't have asked it. Thank you for mentioning EXAR I will check it.

Comment: @UncleBod but on these pads is connected the encoder board of my C52.

Comment: @ecm it is about the encoder I will correct it thank you.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "bottleneck", as I don't understand how the ordinary meaning of the term (part of a system that has the lowest performance, thus limiting the entire system to that level of performance) applies in this situation. Can you explain what would be limited by said IC that could be higher performance otherwise?

Comment: @occipita I mean costwise or maybe availabily or providers conflicts. Maybe it is not clear and maybe bottleneck is not the good word I am sorry.

Comment: @PaulGhobril PAL, like NTSC or SECAM encoding isn't a huge task, and can be done with a reasonable number of analogue components. Especially if all signal components are already delivered in an appropriate way. While using a chip is a cost reduction measure, it's not a big one in itself, but mostly for board production thru less components to be drilled and placed. Other than that [Justme's Answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18206/6659) covers everything about this particular case.

Comment: @Raffzahn you make a great point, but integration has driven technology development throughout history, this is an example of integration, you package and optimize a technology for broader use. Not every company wants to or has the ability to hire a team to validate a discrete design and integration turns that piece into something reusable, It also, therefore, removes duplication of effort, so integration is demanded by the market.

Comment: @crasic Erm ... it might be a good idea to see this in the context of the time when that console was made, a time when these abilities were standard. Even more so with TV manufacturers (and there were still many back then) with their standing force of engineers trained in discrete analogue since decades. It wasn't an age of pop up companies fast hiring and crunching out a product to satisfy startup investors.

Comment: @Raffzahn , sure that is true, but  is still dollars, kopeks, or dinar paying full time employees that could be driving actual core business. The business realities are as much true then as they are now,  and at some point having broadly compatible video output became an expectation and not a differentiator and so integration won, even if a discrete solution is performant. With respect to time period "large scale integration" was coined in the 50s.

Comment: @crasic Well, but the question isn't so much how development came over 30+ years, but how a company handled it in 1977 when such an analogue setup was an of the shelf design. Not uch to think about, so it comes down to production. Which makes this case even more interesting as Philips was at the time as well a major chip producer digital and analogue (and Magnavox their US brand). So there was a PAL chip, but a discrete setup for SECAM units that came _later_ than NTSC and PAL. I guess theydid know how to count already back then. Funny side note: France (SECAM) was **the** main G7000 market.

Comment: The Molex KK 254 with the friction lock on the bottom makes for an awkward design. Because it's inboard of the edge there are slots in the PCB. Seems that it would be easier to use the KK with lock at the top.

Comment: Found this info because I too wondered why Philips didn't mention the part number in their service manual and apparently tried to hide the part number on the machines themselves as well. Sadly, I also can't find a datasheet for it! First, I thought maybe it was because Philips probably had their own PAL encoder chips at that time and didn't want anyone to know they used another brand ... but then I realised that not a single chip on the PCB is Philips brand (while they definitely did produce the regular 74 series at the time too). It's a mystery... I just want to know what kind of signal comes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The PAL video encoder was not a bottleneck of any kind.

It is left out because the unit is not a PAL model, but a SECAM model, which needs a different kind of encoder. So the chip is not needed and it would be useless and just cause extra cost and power consumption in the SECAM model.

The necessary SECAM encoder is integrated to the separate board with the RF modulator.

The IC679 PAL encoder has EXAR logo and model number reads 612160-3.